# How to display data uploaded by different users in a general list through firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase

I am making an app in which the user will authenticate themselves and store information, say related to food detail. Firebase will store this information corresponding to each userID. I want that whenever any user opens the app, he should see a list of all the food details uploaded by different users. I know only how to access data of the current user. Even for a particular user, i want to access a given field of all users present in Firebase realtime database.

Comment: You want to use [Firebase Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) or [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), both are Firebase databases? If you are looking for Cloud Firestore, I recommend you see one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** in which I have explained step by step how you can add and read data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all the info available from your question, here are my points in my experience i would have done.

you will have to have these data for the food stored in a common location where your security rules permits for read and write but only if the user is authenticated

[realtime database security rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

next, I will keep all these food data in the common location as earlier said and a condensed version of it at each user's hierarchical level with the same identifier( document id or reference) as in the common location for easy retrieval should I want to.

[working with a list of data in firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) at this stage, assuming you will be loading it into a listview/recyclerview, on receival of new object, you can just load it into your adapter and you are good to go.

- Even for a particular user, i want to access a given field of all users present in Firebase realtime database.

Just make them security rules to that field readable by any logged in user and then, use the following link to know how to access the data. 
[reading data from firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). Hope this helps. If you want more explanation, give more details on your use case and the hierarchical structure of your database.